# Samsung induction range pot sensor non-functional

Tags: range, samsung

Model number NE58H9970WS/AC

Issue: Large right front burner will not heat -- displays the code for 'no pot detected'. Condition persists with any pot, with or without contents. All other functions are normal.

I read the very helpful thread at [Samsung induction stove not detecting cookware](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/190811/samsung-induction-stove-not-detecting-cookware). There, pairs of burners (left or right) exhibited a similar problem. Unlike the posts on that thread, only one burners malfunctions on my range, requiring a modified diagnosis.

Does the failure of a single burner eliminate the PCBs as the source of the problem? I could not tell if the load sensing function for both burners was channeled through a single circuit for the PCB controlling that side. Can anyone here say?

Per the earlier thread, I disassembled the range and examined the wiring and the PCBs. I found no wiring issues. Careful examination of the solder points on the three PCBs found no clear failure points. One point was marginally questionable, and I re-soldered it. No change to the problem.

If the PCBs are not the problem, what remains seems to be the button sensor in that burner, and the wiring from the button sensor to the PCB. As noted, the wiring appears in good condition. Does anyone have info about failure of the sensor button? As this part is comparatively cheap, I will try replacing this next.

As always, questions, comments, and insights are appreciated.

Comment: Based on many questions about various types of appliances here and several partly functional ranges seen on my local craigslist, I think the problem is that it says "Samsung" on it. ;^)

Comment: I guess there are differing opinions on their appliances... I have a Samsung microwave oven bought well over two decades ago, that's still performing well :)

Comment: just a thought, were you able to test the buttons with a multi meter? I would imagine they would read as an "open circuit" when they are raised, and when they are pressed in, it would show resistance. Or perhaps the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using a large enough pot for that "burner"? On my GE, I have pots that work fine on the three normal induction rings but not on the large-pot one, and I have seen undersized pots that will not be accepted by any.

I presume you have already checked that a magnet will stick to the pot. If it won't, you can't use that pot on an induction cooktop. (If it's oven-safe you might want to retain it for that use.)

(I have seen people try to use a magnetic saucepan to heat a nonmagnetic pot indirectly. Works about as well or poorly as a double-boiler ever works.)